# nginx-tomcat setup: readv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading upstream, client

Tags: tomcat, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a setup with Nginx as a front-facing server and Tomcat instances as upstream servers in a reverse proxy setup.

I keep getting this error on various requests:
2017/07/20 11:43:11 [error] 16892#16892: *3154964 readv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading upstream, client: , server: myserver, request: "GET // HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http:///", host: "myserver", referrer: "https://myserver/"

What does this error mean and how do I fix it?

Below are the relevant parts of Nginx conf directives:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 2000;
        multi_accept on;
        use epoll;
}
http {
    upstream backend  {
        server  localhost:8080 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=120s;
    }
    location /path {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
    :
    :
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    proxy_connect_timeout       1000;
    proxy_send_timeout          1000;
    proxy_read_timeout          1000;
    send_timeout                1000;
   :
   :
}
```

Comment: Your nginx config?

Comment: I am getting what looks like the same error

Comment: server {
    listen <my-server>:443;
    server_name <my-server>;

    ssl    on;
    ssl_certificate    /etc/pki/tls/certs/my.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    /etc/pki/tls/private/my.key;

    location / {
        root /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/ROOT;

        proxy_pass                          http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_redirect                      http://localhost:8080 $scheme://localhost;
        proxy_set_header Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't look like comments are the best place to post this code I will create a separate question and reference this one